# Yii - Understanding operators to build SQL via CDBCriteria with LIKE condition

Tags: yii

Here's the SQL I want to achieve via Yii `CDBCriteria` :

```
WHERE 
    (
        (field1 LIKE '%value1%') AND (field1 LIKE '%value2%')
    ) OR (
        (field2 LIKE '%value1%') AND (field2 LIKE '%value2%')
    ) OR (
        (field3 LIKE '%value1%') AND (field3 LIKE '%value2%')
    )
```

This will return the row if a string contains 'value1' or 'value2' in any order. ex.:

> Lorem value1 ipsum value2 sir dolor amet.

OR

> Lorem value2 ipsum value1 sir dolor amet.

But will return nothing if there's only one value.

What I've tried (from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908460/yii-combining-addcolumncondition-in-cdbcriteria)) :

```
$c = new CDbCriteria;
$c->addColumnCondition(array('field1 LIKE' => '%value1%', 'field1 LIKE' => '%value2%'), 'AND', 'OR');
$c->addColumnCondition(array('field2 LIKE' => '%value1%', 'field2 LIKE' => '%value2%'), 'AND', 'OR');
$c->addColumnCondition(array('field3 LIKE' => '%value1%', 'field3 LIKE' => '%value2%'), 'AND', 'OR');
```

But this is not how to use it with `LIKE` condition and it returns only the second compare because the key is the same for the same field :

```
(
    (field1 LIKE='%value2%') OR (field2 LIKE='%value2%')
) OR (field3 LIKE='%value2%')
```

So I've tried with compare condition :

```
$c->compare('field1', 'value1', true);
$c->compare('field1', 'value2', true, 'OR');
$c->compare('field2', 'value1', true, 'AND');
$c->compare('field2', 'value2', true, 'OR');
$c->compare('field3', 'value1', true, 'AND');
$c->compare('field3', 'value2', true, 'OR');
```

OR

```
$c->addSearchCondition('field1', 'value1', false);
$c->addSearchCondition('field1', 'value2', false, 'OR');
$c->addSearchCondition('field2', 'value1', false);
$c->addSearchCondition('field2', 'value2', false, 'OR');
$c->addSearchCondition('field3', 'value1', false);
$c->addSearchCondition('field3', 'value2', false, 'OR');
```

But I could not work it out to return the condition I want. Here's what I get :

```
(
    (
        (
            (
                (field1 LIKE '%value1%') OR (field1 LIKE '%value2%')
            ) 
            AND (field2 LIKE '%value1%')
        ) 
        OR (field2 LIKE '%value2%')
    ) 
    AND (field3 LIKE '%value1%')
) OR (field3 LIKE '%value2%')
```

So if anybody have an idea how to achieve this, help me :)

Comment: Are you sure you wanna call that query? Basically value1 and value2 need to be the same all the time if you wanna that query return something. If that is the case, why not skip query if they are not the same? Only call query when values are identical: `if($value1 == $value2) //call simplified query`

Edit: Sorry... It's "like" not exact match.

Comment: value1 and value2 are always different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$c->addCondition("field1 like :value1 and field1 like :value2", "OR");
$c->addCondition("field2 like :value1 and field2 like :value2", "OR");
$c->addCondition("field3 like :value1 and field3 like :value2", "OR");
$c->params = array(':value1' => '%'. $value1 .'%', ':value2' => '%'. $value2 .'%');
```

Alternative:

```
$c2 = new CDbCriteria;
$c2->addSearchCondition("field2", ':value1');
$c2->addSearchCondition("field2", ':value2');

$c3 = new CDbCriteria;
$c3->addSearchCondition("field3", ':value1');
$c3->addSearchCondition("field3", ':value2');

$c->addSearchCondition("field1", ':value1');
$c->addSearchCondition("field1", ':value2');
$c->mergeWith($c2, false);
$c->mergeWith($c3, false);
```

Comment: Yes, this could work, but I want to know if there another way to do this without concatenate all the like conditions into 1 condition.

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault Added alternative. Just have to bind parameters properly.

Comment: This is a nice alternative, Thanks!

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault Thanks for accepting the answer. I updated it to reflect your suggestion (`false` instead of `'OR'` for `mergeWith` method).